# How to pass parameters to a collection view server call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, marionette

I am developing a Backbone.Marionette web app.
In this app I got a project collection view. Each project can have different statuses (pending,active,completed). I would like to add buttons to the list page where the user can click and the models are updated.

For example, if the user clicks the Pending button only projects that are pending should be shown.

My question is, how can I pass parameters to a collection view call (a server call). Normally I would just do this: http://domain.com/projects?status=pending. I guess I am basically saying how can I fetch with parameters?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1):

Your collection:

```
//...

fetchProjects : function (status) {
  this.fetch({
    data : {status:status}
  });
}
```

And on click just execute:

```
yourCollection.fetchProjects('pending');
```

Comment: A looks cool! But how can I auto update the list of models when I fetch new content?

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch models will be updated automatically (new model will be merged with old model). In case if you want to replace collection with new models - pass `{reset: true}` as option. But if you are asking about updating the view you can do the next thing: in you view listen for the 'sync' (http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) event and update page with new items. This event fires after successfully `fetch` complete.

Comment: Not sure exactly how to listen for sync? How can I do that?

Comment: How to work with events you can find here: http://backbonejs.org/#Events - in your view you can do something like this: `this.listenTo(yourCollection, 'sync', this.render)`